# RemoteSwingLibraryTimeoutError: Agent port not received before timeout

Tags: java, eclipse, robotframework

I am trying to run a basic robotframework test with RemoteSwingLibrary, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I was able to run the following test just fine with SwingLibrary:

```
*** Settings ***
Library SwingLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Foobar Test
    Start Application fully.qualified.name.of.my.class
```

I am running it from within Eclipse via the robot framework standalone jar. I put robotframework-3.0.2.jar and swinglibrary-1.9.7.jar on my class path, created a new run configuration using my projects default classpath with the main class being org.robotframework.RobotFramework. In the arguments, I specify the name of my test file.

So, that seems to work fine. Then I tried to do almost exactly the same thing with RemoteSwingLibrary:

```
*** Settings ***
Library RemoteSwingLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Foobar Test
    Start Application    my_app    java fully.qualified.name.of.my.class
```

I replaced the swinglibrary jar on my classpath with remoteswinglibrary-2.2.1.jar and I ran the same test. The output says:

```
console: Failed to install '': java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cp0.
==============================================================================
Remotetest                                                                    
==============================================================================
Foobar Test                                                           | FAIL |
RemoteSwingLibraryTimeoutError: Agent port not received before timeout
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Remotetest                                                            | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\<path>\output.xml
Log:     C:\<path>\log.html
Report:  C:\<path>\report.html
```

(note that the "console: Failed to install..." part is normal and I don't think I need to be concerned about it)

When I dig into the report for the Start Application Keyword, it says

```
13:48:40.070 INFO Link to stdout 
13:48:40.070 INFO Link to stderr 
13:48:40.070 INFO -javaagent:"C:<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__"=127.0.0.1:63110 
13:48:40.071 INFO Starting process:
                  java fully.qualified.name.of.my.class 
13:49:40.145 INFO Failed to start application: Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 307, in start_application
               File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 353, in _application_started
               File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 373, in _get_agent_address
             RemoteSwingLibraryTimeoutError: Agent port not received before timeout
13:49:40.155 INFO Waiting for process to complete. 
13:49:40.165 INFO Process completed. 
13:49:40.165 INFO STDOUT: Error occurred during initialization of VM
                  agent library failed to init: instrument 
13:49:40.175 INFO STDERR: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__
                  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:"C:<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__"=127.0.0.1:63110
                  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.policy="C:\<UserFolder>\
                  AppData\Local\Temp\2\grant_all_f_vfit.policy" 
13:49:40.195 FAIL RemoteSwingLibraryTimeoutError: Agent port not received before timeout
```

I'm not sure if this hunch is really founded on anything, but my suspicion is that there's a classpath issue. I would think that when I call the Start Application keyword with "java fully.qualified.name.of.my.class" I would probably have to pass along my classpath. I was hoping that maybe I wouldn't since the non-remote version seems to handle that just fine (probably because its running my app in the same JVM as I launched robot framework in, and that already included everything I needed in my classpath).

So if that's the issue, I can probably fix it by using the -cp option in my java command. However, the classpath for this particular project is actually quite long (my project is dependent on a lot of other projects) and I would rather not have to list it all out. Also, when I add a new dependency down the road, I would rather not have to update the classpath in my test file as well.

Is there some magic way that I can pass the current classpath along to the remote app? Or perhaps some other solution to this problem?

**Update**

I tried again with -cp and my giant classpath and it gave me the same errors, so its possible that my classpath has nothing to do with whatever is going on.

I also tried specifying the port number explicitly and it gives me slightly different output (though it still doesn't work). I also discovered that there's a debug setting that gives a little more detail. Here's me new setup:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RemoteSwingLibrary    debug=True    port=8242

*** Test Cases ***
Foobar Test
    Start Application    my_app    java -cp <classpath> <fully.qualified.name.of.my.class>    remote_port=8242
```

And here is my new output:

```
13:48:40.070 INFO Link to stdout 
13:48:40.070 INFO Link to stderr 
13:48:40.070 DEBUG Picked old JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=''
13:48:40.070 DEBUG Picked old _JAVA_OPTIONS=''
13:48:40.070 INFO -javaagent:"C:<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__"=127.0.0.1:51509:DEBUG 
13:48:40.070 DEBUG Set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-javaagent:"C:<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__"=127.0.0.1:8242:APPORT=8242:DEBUG'
13:48:40.070 DEBUG SET _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Djava.security.policy="C:\<UserFolder>\AppData\Local\Temp\4\grant_all_haud6t.policy"'
13:48:40.071 INFO Starting process:
                  java  -cp <classpath> <fully.qualified.name.of.my.class> 
13:48:40.071 DEBUG Process configuration:
                   cwd:     C:<PathToProject>
                   shell:   True
                   stdout:  C:<PathToProject>\<someBigPath>.txt
                   stderr:  C:<PathToProject>\<someBigPath>.txt
                   alias:   my_app
                   env:     None
13:48:40.100 DEBUG Returned old JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=''
13:48:40.100 DEBUG Returned old _JAVA_OPTIONS=''
13:48:40.102 INFO  connection to started application at 127.0.0.1:8242
13:48:40.120 DEBUG remote swinglibrary instantiated
13:48:40.121 DEBUG remote services instantiated
13:48:40.121 INFO  waiting for api at 127.0.0.1:8242
13:49:40.145 INFO Failed to start application: Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 307, in start_application
               File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 357, in _application_started
               File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 344, in _wait_for_api
             RuntimeError: Connecting to api at 127.00.1:8242 has failed: ''
13:49:40.155 INFO Waiting for process to complete. 
13:49:40.165 INFO Process completed. 
13:49:40.165 INFO STDOUT: Error occurred during initialization of VM
                  agent library failed to init: instrument 
13:49:40.175 INFO STDERR: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__
                  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:"C:<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__"=127.0.0.1:8242:APPORT=8242:DEBUG
                  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.policy="C:\<UserFolder>\
                  AppData\Local\Temp\2\grant_all_f_vfit.policy" 
13:49:40.195 FAIL Connecting to api at 127.0.0.1:8242 has failed: ''
13:49:40.195 DEBUG Traceback (most recent call last):
                     File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 498, in run_keyword
                     File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 307, in start_application
                     File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 357, in _application_started
                     File "__pyclasspath__/RemoteSwingLibrary.py", line 344, in _wait_for_api
```

**Yet another update**

I think that this may have something to do with the "`__pyclasspath__`" that shows up in the error message. I put my java command in a .bat file preceded by a "set" command to list my environment variables. I can run the .bat file from the command line just fine (it launches the java app).

Then I modified my .robot file to do:

```
Foobar Test
    Start Application    my_app    cd robotframework/tests && Run.bat    remote_port=8242
```

I get essentially the same error output that I got before:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__
```

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:"__pyclasspath__"=127.0.0.1:8242:APPORT=8242:DEBUG
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.policy="C:\\AppData\Local\Temp\1\grant_all_lgirs7.policy"

The environment that my batch script prints out appears the same except for JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and _JAVA_OPTIONS (which match with what the error output says). There is no environment variable called `__pyclasspath__` so I'm wondering if that's the issue.

I set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in my cmd environment to match the output that I saw from my robot run and now I get the same error message when I try to run my .bat script from the command line, so that environment variable seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I came up with *a* fix, though its definitely not an *ideal* fix.

I found out that when the framework kicks of my remote app, it sets:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:"C:\<pathToProject>\__pyclasspath__
```

But `__pyclasspath__` is not actually an environment variable. I figured out that the javaagent has to point to the remote framework library, so I decided to just set it explicitly.

So now I changed my robot file to something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library RemoteSwingLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Foobar Test
    Start Application    my_app    run.bat    remote_port=1234
```

And then made a file called run.bat that does:

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:"C:\<pathToProject\lib\remoteswinglibrary-2.2.1.jar"=127.0.0.1:1234:APPORT=1234
java -cp <classPath> fully.qualified.name.of.class
```

This is obviously sort of a hacky solution and it will take a little work to make it portable (I'll need to get rid of the hardcoded "pathToProject" and also make it support Linux environments as well). It also requires hardcoding in a port, whereas it would be nice if the robotframework could just select a port for me.

So, I would definitely like to see a better solution if anyone can find one, but for now, this will at least work.